# AngularJS $locationChangeSuccess event Fired On Initial Load of Page

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In the Simple AngularJS Page, $locationChangeSuccess is fired on the initial load of the page.

It could be useful If the event is not fired on the initial load.

Could anyone know the reason why this event $locationChangeSuccess is firing in initial load

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('myCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', '$rootScope', function($scope, $location, $rootScope){
 


 console.log("My Controller");

  $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl, newState) {
        console.log("route Changed");
        console.log(event);
        console.log(newUrl);
        console.log(oldUrl);
        console.log(newState);
     });
      $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, newUrl, oldUrl, newState) {
        console.log("route change started");
     });
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <title>HTML BolierPlate</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/lib/reset.css"></link>
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/mystyle.css"></link>
  <script src="/lib/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="/lib/jquery.min.js" ></script>
  <script src="bower_components/angular/angular.js"></script>

     <script src="js/myscript.js" ></script>
      
  <script>
   jQuery(function($){



   });
   
  </script>
  <style>
   .font32{font-size:32px}
   
  </style>

 </head>

 <body data-ng-app="myApp" data-ng-controller="myCtrl">
     
     Welcome to BoilerPlate!!!

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What about firing on locationChangeStart (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location#$locationChangeStart)? Success is fired even on starts.

Comment: Routers together with the [ng-view directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/directive/ngView) use the first `locationChangeStart` event to determine which controller and which template to load. This may also involve a re-direct under certain conditions.

Comment: @georgeawg in code the ng-view is not used, this is just standalone page just with event handler

Comment: @MatthewCampbell locationchangeStart also firing two times, check the console

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with the `locationChangeStart` event? Both the `ngRoute` and `ui-route` routers find it useful. What do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 1):

Add a dirty flag to check whether is it first time load or next time.